# Guava transform listenableFuture only when requested

Tags: guava

I have a listenableFuture, and I want to chain another listenableFuture that will run only when the original ListenableFuture will run, so something like that:

```
ListenableFuture<Response> respFuture = Futures.transform(
                    listenableFuture,
                    res -> res.doSomething()
            );
```

I want the `doSomething` to run only when `respFuture` is invoked (either by calling `get()` or `addListener` or something similar.

However, when I call `transform` the code is run immediately.
Is there a way to defer the run to when the first listenableFuture is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. Return listenableFuture itself, without transforming it, and then call e.g. listenableFuture.get().doSomething() at the point you know you want to call doSomething().

The whole idea of Futures.transform is to bundle the future with a transformation of the future, which is very often exactly what you want to do. But in your case, it makes more sense to do what I suggested above.

Comment: The problem is that I'm developing a library, so the caller will have to add this on his code, which I don't want.
However, I get your point that this is a mis-use of Futures.

Comment: Well, if the idea is that you only want to doSomething on the caller side, you could always return a ListenableFuture<ThingWrapper>, where ThingWrapper is obtained via transformation as you do above, contains the produced object as a private member, and has a single getViaDoSomething() method (with some more client-friendly name) which returns thing.doSomething() .